# Multi screen RDP in Windows 8.1 Enterprise

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8.1

I have just flattened my machine and installed Windows 8.1 Enterprise Edition.

I have used the Hyper-V to create a virtual machine for my Software Development stuff, on my VM I have also installed Windows 8.1 Enterprise Edition. I want to have two screen support when using this VM (not using /span)

Both the Hyper-V viewer and Remote Desktop give me a tickbox to "Use all my monitors for the remote session". However even with it ticked (and even when I tried the /multimon switch on the command line), I only get a single screen.

Am I missing something - this should be supported in Enterprise edition, right?
Is there some extra config I need to do on the RDP host?

Forgive me if it's an obvious question, I'm more a developer and just stumbling through ;-)

Cheers!
Ben

Comment: Superuser might be a better place to ask this.

Comment: @AtillaFiliz *"[Windows 8 Enterprise is available exclusively as a benefit of Microsoft Software Assurance through Volume Licensing programs such as Select Plus, Enterprise Agreement, and Enterprise Subscription Agreement](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8/default.aspx)"* -- I'm guessing home users aren't joining a Volume License program.

Comment: @jscott I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/07/01/using-multiple-monitors-in-remote-desktop-session.aspx talks about setting up and also the limits for multimon for RDS on win7 and server 2008r2 - might apply here?

There are a few settings associated with the Remote Desktop Multimon feature that can be used to restrict the number of monitors and resolution that clients use to connect.

Restricting the maximum number of monitors:

The Remote Desktop Multimon feature provides an option to restrict the number of monitors a user can use to connect. By default, RDP protocol supports a maximum of 16 monitors. This number can be restricted to any value between 1 and 16 using one of the following three approaches:
1.Using the “Limit maximum number of monitors per session” setting in the Remote Desktop Configuration Tool (tsconfig.msc) as shown below: 
[image]
2.Setting the “Limit maximum number of monitors” machine group policy as shown below:

[image]
3.By setting the MaxMonitors property in the Win32_TSClientSetting WMI class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383778(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Good effort, but all this info seems to be about restricting the maximum number of monitors, not enabling a new one. I'm not able to reproduce the problem, as ticking the "Use all monitors..." checkbox works for me when RDP'ing to a Win 8.1 virtual machine.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions - I tried option 2, amending it in group policy, I enabled the policy and set it to 16 monitors (hah, I wish) but sadly, still only uses one of my screens. Thank you again for the attempt! :)